Ubuntu Studio 24.04 freezes when copying 1 TB of files
I'm looking forward to making creative things with Ubuntu Studio 24.04, but for now, I'm stuck trying to resolve OS issues.
The biggest problem is that when I try to copy 1.04 TB of ISOs and VMs to a secondary internal drive, it usually fails during the process -- I've tried multiple times and on two similar workstations. I saved /var/log/* but I didn't see any good error messages in there
I've been occasionally working on this and testing this for the past three or four weeks. There used to also be bad keyboard and mouse issues too but I think that cleared up over time with updates, though I'll re-test (Wayland) for the keyboard/mouse issues if/when the file issue gets resolved. I've been mainly testing with X11 -- both X11 and Wayland have the freeze issue when copying 1TB of files
Details:
I copy from an external USB 2TB spinning hdd to an internal 22TB spinning hdd. I manually copy about 100GB at a time using Dolphin. It can fail at about 40% of the way of the entire job, but recently it's been failing at about 95% of the way, where there are 1000s of tiny files (*.c, *.bas, etc) -- most of the other files are larger *.iso or *.ova files. When the failure happens, the screen is frozen and no mouse or keyboard events are accepted. A hard shutdown (press and hold power button for 10+ seconds) and restart is then required.
test systems:
Dell 5810
E5-1650v4 32GB ram, 1 TB SSD for OS, 22TB HDD for data, 1TB SSD for data
Dell 5810
E5-1660v4 32GB ram, 1 TB SSD for OS, 22TB HDD for data, 1TB SSD for data
The computers are from 2017 but the drives are new Crucial TLC or WD Red drives
Video cards are Nvidia M4000 (I like how Nvidia just works with Ubuntu Studio)
I used memtest86+ to test the RAM on both and no errors were reported.
lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL 
NAME FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT SIZE FSUSED MODEL 
sda 931.5G CT1000MX500SSD1 
├─sda1 vfat /boot/efi 1G 6.1M 
└─sda2 ext4 / 930.5G 25.3G 
sdb ext4 /mnt/hdd22tb 20T 3.8T WDC WD221KFGX-68B9KN0 
sdc ext4 /mnt/ssd1tb 931.5G 178.9G CT1000MX500SSD1

~/Documents/crashfiles_20241129/log$ lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,
MODEL NAME FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT SIZE FSUSED MODEL 
sda 931.5G CT1000MX500SSD1 
├─sda1 vfat /boot/efi 1G 6.1M 
└─sda2 ext4 / 930.5G 26.5G 
sdb ext4 /mnt/hdd22tb 20T 3.3T WDC WD221KFGX-68B9KN0 
sdc ext4 /mnt/ssd1tb 931.5G 32K CT1000MX500SSD1 
sr0 1024M HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM DTA0N

~/Documents/crashfiles_20241129/log$ df -i 
Filesystem   Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse%  Mounted on 
tmpfs       4097924   1553   4096371    1%  /run 
/dev/sda2  60981248 529659  60451589    1%  / 
tmpfs       4097924      1   4097923    1%  /dev/shm 
tmpfs       4097924      5   4097919    1%  /run/lock 
efivarfs 0 0 0 - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars 
/dev/sdc   61054976     12  61054964    1%  /mnt/ssd1tb 
/dev/sdb  335708160  28009 335680151    1%  /mnt/hdd22tb

I retried the test copy of 1.04TB of files on the two workstations using the command line:
cp -Rav {source} {dest}
The result was that it was successful on my E5-1650v4 (6 core) computer this time but failed on my E5-1660v4 (8 core) computer -- it worked until it didn't work and froze the computer completely -- there were no on-screen error messages
I need to move forward so my workaround for now will be to use Dolphin like I originally started doing and I'll copy about 100GB at a time -- when Ubuntu Studio freezes on these workstations, I'll hard-shutdown the PC, reboot, and will delete the failed batch of directories and retry copying
Let me know if there are any further debugging or log info that needs to be posted.

What formats are partitions? lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL  also inodes df -i

Have you tried copying using commands like cp or rsync in the terminal? If you did, add the exact command with the options you used and the exact errors. Copy and paste from the terminal to the question above.

phoenixadmin@phoenix:~$ lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT     SIZE FSUSED MODEL
sda                              931.5G        CT1000MX500SSD1
├─sda1 vfat         /boot/efi        1G   6.1M
└─sda2 ext4         /            930.5G  25.3G
sdb    ext4         /mnt/hdd22tb    20T   3.8T WDC WD221KFGX-68B9KN0
sdc    ext4         /mnt/ssd1tb  931.5G 178.9G CT1000MX500SSD1

phoenixadmin@phoenix:~$ df -i
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs            4097942   1506   4096436    1% /run
/dev/sda2       60981248 525358  60455890    1% /
tmpfs            4097942      3   4097939    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4097942      5   4097937    1% /run/lock
efivarfs               0      0         0     - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sda1              0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sdb       335708160  28748 335679412    1% /mnt/hdd22tb
/dev/sdc        61054976     68  61054908    1% /mnt/ssd1tb

philadelphiaadmin@philadelphia:~/Documents/crashfiles_20241129/log$ lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT     SIZE FSUSED MODEL
sda                              931.5G        CT1000MX500SSD1
├─sda1 vfat         /boot/efi        1G   6.1M
└─sda2 ext4         /            930.5G  26.5G
sdb    ext4         /mnt/hdd22tb    20T   3.3T WDC WD221KFGX-68B9KN0
sdc    ext4         /mnt/ssd1tb  931.5G    32K CT1000MX500SSD1
sr0                               1024M        HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM DTA0N

philadelphiaadmin@philadelphia:~/Documents/crashfiles_20241129/log$ df -i
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs            4097924   1553   4096371    1% /run
/dev/sda2       60981248 529659  60451589    1% /
tmpfs            4097924      1   4097923    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4097924      5   4097919    1% /run/lock
efivarfs               0      0         0     - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sdc        61054976     12  61054964    1% /mnt/ssd1tb
/dev/sdb       335708160  28009 335680151    1% /mnt/hdd22tb

a few weeks ago, it seemed like mouse and keyboard reliability was affected by lots of disk activity -- that issue appeared to have went away or was reduced with recent updates
There was an extremely noticeable keyboard issue when installing from ISO... very consistent -- when I would try to correct the hostname by pressing back-space in the hostname textbox, the screen would lockup -- maybe 30% of the time it would return control and I could continue -- other times, I would just have to reboot and start over - I believe this is with Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio

regarding the installation hostname textbox issue... I've seen this reported one time on a facebook group I'm on (in addition to my personal experience with the problem) -- my work-around is now to accept the default entry and later edit in /etc/hostname -- I'm reporting these keyboard/mouse/IO issues together incase they happen to be related

I haven't yet done a cp or rsync for this 1TB copy (I usually try to copy only ~100GB at a time so that the plastic wrapped external HD gets an occasional cool-down break) - I'll think about trying that, though it seems to completely and immediately freeze / lockup with no logging or complaints when this problem occurs

Please post terminal output in question, just about unreadable as a comment.

@PW2 Please do not use comments for additional information about the question. Always edit your question. There is an edit button below your question. Use it.

In addition to cp or rsync (I would suggest you try both), also try copying the file with an otherwise idle system.  Don't try doing other things that are hard disk intensive while also copying.

In the case of these failed tests, I am only using the workstations to do the copies and no other user applications are running hot -- the resulting writes should be mostly to perfectly sequential -- since these failures have been fairly consistent, when I redo these tests, I put the computers into airplane mode so there are no automated updates or other activity -- both of these computers are recent clean installs of Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 with no additional software installed except for the current version of VirtualBox (which was not running at the time of the copies)

Search this site for "slow copy" or "data transfer rate" and see mitigations others have uses/attempted.  WD Red uses the SMR (Shingled Magnetic Recording) doesn't it, so that's slow enough to be a problem.  Do you have any indication of disk activity (blinking light, noise,...)?  When system buffers fill up, things do drag to a crawl, with 10s of seconds on mouse/cursor movement -- maybe the "freeze" is just things slowing to kilobytes/sec copy speed, while thrashing fragmented memory.

Google AI mentioned: "The WD221KFGX hard drive, which is a Western Digital Red Pro model, uses CMR (Conventional Magnetic Recording) technology, not SMR; meaning it is a CMR drive"
The recent "cp" command was left running over night and it's failure time remained on screen on the desktop clock
The OS can have slowdowns but in my opinion should never lock up completely

The source USB hard drive does continue constant non-intermittent blinking when these freezes happen (it doesn't make technical sense; when the freeze happens, the frozen time on-screen matches the last time in log files, no matter how many extra hours passed by)

(to be clear, when the workstation is frozen, the blinking LED on the source USB drive doesn't look like occasional read attempts and it also doesn't look like an unmounted drive -- it's a faster (than disconnected drive) paced constant, forever blinking)

With fragged memory, the writes may be very small.  Basic problem is when reads faster than writes, memory buffers fill and memory fragments, and system slows. From a terminal, try using nocache before the copy command to prevent buffering the input, then try a program with user space buffers you can make large (tar or cpio) to help prevent fragmentation, last resort to slow reads, use USB2 (even it's faster than 10s of kilobytes/sec).  Other things like dirty bytes and ratios, scheduler, ... may be attempted, but I've never bothered.

I've been moving large amounts of data using Windows or Linux with xeon or simpler equipment over the years -- there is something clearly broken.  I try to be kind to the OS and equipment and usually keep the copy commands to about 100GB at a time -- 2010 class OSs and equipment have been able to handle this type of job, do the clean up and continue with no extra tweaks needed to avoid complete failures

Submitting smaller jobs allows buffers to flush before the next job, so that sort of delay may be emulated with the -L xxxxx option to tar (max size to write to a tape, asks for user input when next tape mounted), watch free memory for enough available space before hitting return.  The copy issue is not new, goes back forever. Launchpad bugs 1090715 , 1802821, etc. Askubuntu questions 995946, 1113235,...
